# How to set the size from a QDockwidget

Tags: size, qdockwidget

I'm trying to set the initial size from QDockwidget docks. I tried with QSplitter but so far I couldn't achieve it...

Any suggestions, post, or help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can get head-popping :-(. The [QMainWindoq](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) has a method [resizeDocks](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#resizeDocks), which you can use this way (PyQt5):

```
    docks = [self.dwSource, self.dwDBitems, self.dwProps]
    docksizes = [250,250,250]
    self.resizeDocks(docks, docksizes, Qt.Horizontal)
```

> The sizes will be adjusted such that the maximum and the minimum sizes are respected and the QMainWindow itself will not be resized

You can start from there, but it's not guaranteed it will be applied, in my experience. Often, you have to set `sizePolicy` and `sizeHint` to the particular widgets contained in the docks.